# Как сделать что бы кривая значение была зависимой от кривой безье

Tags: c++, кривые-безье

Имеется метод

```
template<class T>
T getNextValue(T numerator, T denominator, T cfrom, T cto)
{
    return ((numerator / denominator) * (cto - cfrom)) + cfrom;
}
```

И вызывается он вот так

```
getNextValue(1, 10, 0, 255);
```

Суть этого метода найти энную долю от `cto` но как сделать так что бы результат зависел от кривой Безье.

Comment: Вас интересует линейная кривая, кубическая?

Answer (score 0):

Формулировочка, конечно, страдает... Попробуем так для начала:

```
t = numerator / denominator; //0..1
result = Bezier.EvaluateY_ComponentAt(t);//Y-компонент кривой в точке с параметром t
где 
Evaluate = (1-t)^3*P1.y + 3*t*(1-t)^2*P2.y + 3*t^2*(1-t)*P3.y + t^3*P4.y
```